# Closure of a set is the set of limit points.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $S = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \exists (x_n) \subseteq A \; \; \; s.t \; \; x_n \to x \} $

$$ \text{Claim}: \; \overline{A} = S $$

#### Attempt

$ \overline{A} \subseteq S$. Let $y \in \overline{A}$. Then, by definition, $y$ is a limit point of $A$: That is, for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $a \in A$ with $a \neq y$ such that $a \in B(y, \epsilon)$. Since this holds for all $\epsilon$, we can select $\epsilon := \frac{1}{n} $. Let $a = a_n$. Hence, $a_n \in B(y, \frac{1}{n})$ for all $n$. This implies that $||a_n - y || < \frac{1}{n} \implies a_n \to y $. Hence, $y \in S$

$S \subseteq \overline{A}$. Let $x \in S$. Let $(x_n) \subseteq A$. Hence, for all $\epsilon$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, we have $||x_n - x|| < \epsilon $. Select $n = N$, hence we have $||x_N - x || < \epsilon $. Since $x_N \neq x$ and since $x \in B(x_N, \epsilon)$, then we by definition that $x$ is a limit point of $A$. In particular, $S \subseteq \overline{A}$.

Is this a correct solution? I am still a little bit unsure about the first inclusion. Any help would be greatly appreacited. thanks.

Comment: What is your definition of $\overline A$? It seems to be the set of points $x$ such that any neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $A$.

Comment: exactly right..

Comment: If $\overline{A}$ is the closure of $A$ here then from $y\in \overline{A}$ it cannot be concluded that $y$ is a *limit point* of $A$. The conclusion that there is a sequence in $A$ converging to it is okay. Characteristic for limit points is that their neighborhoods contain elements of $A$ different from the point itself (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point). By the second inclusion: what makes you say that $x_N\neq x$? I must leave now, maybe till later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is true,except some points.

In firts inclusion, You should start with let $y\in \bar{A}$ then $y\in A$ or $y$ is a limit point.

if $y\in A$ take $x_n=y$ as constant sequence so $y\in S$.If $y$ is a limit point then ...

rest of arguments is same with yours.

In second argument, after saying that if $|x_n-x|< \epsilon$ then if $x_n=x$ for some $n\implies x\in A$ you are done.if not,then $x$ is a limit point thus, $x\in \bar A$.

Notes:$\bar A=A\cup A^{'}$ where $A^{'}$ is limit points of $A$.

Comment: I'd say his argument for the first inclusion is fine after removing "with $a\neq y$", isn't it?

Comment: I think problems is that OP thinks that $\bar{A}$ is equal to set of limit points $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Purely looking at the title of your question: the closure of a set is in general *not* the set of its limit points. For instance let $A$ be a singleton. Then the closure of $A$ is (if the topology is $T_1$) $A$ itself. However the set of its limit points is the empty set.

$x$ is a limit point of $A$ if and only if it is in the closure of $A-\{x\}$.